# Set PDF/A properties using filecontents package

Tags: hyperref, pdfx, filecontents

I would like to provide the follwing class:

```
\ProvidesClass{pdfatest}[2018/04/12 V0.1 PDF/A Test]
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\cnumber}[1]{\def\@cnumber{#1}}
\newcommand{\cauthor}[1]{\def\@cauthor{#1}}

% Set PDF/A properties using pdfx and filecontens packages
\usepackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{Certificate of Calibration No \@cnumber} % not working because \@cnumber not defined
    \Author{\@cauthor} % not working because \@cauthor not defined
\end{filecontents}
```

The problem is that I can't set the `\Title` and `\Author` inside the `filecontents` block when I'm using variables `\@...`.

Using `\hypersetup` inside `\AtBeginDocument` I was able to set the properties, see the following code:

```
% Set PDF properties using the hyperref package.
% Not used, because it's not working with PDF/A.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle=Certificate of Calibration No \@cnumber,
        pdfauthor=\@cauthor
    }
}
```

I tried as well to put `filecontents` block inside `\AtBeginDocument`. But I get an `Undefined control sequence` error if I do that.

I'm using my class for example like that:

```
\documentclass{pdfatest}

\cnumber{123-45678}
\cauthor{My Name}

\begin{document}
Bla bla ...
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how I can use the `filecontents` block with variables in my class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pdfx` package should be loaded at the end of the preamble, this prevents `\Title` etc. being undefined when `\begin{filecontents}...\end{filecontents}` is used.

So load the `etoolbox` package and wrap the loading of `pdfx` into `\AtEndPreamble`.

The `\@c....` macros are written unexpanded anyway and only expanded at the time of writing the meta data.

```
\ProvidesClass{pdfatest}[2018/04/12 V0.1 PDF/A Test]
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{article}


\newcommand{\cnumber}[1]{\def\@cnumber{#1}}
\newcommand{\cauthor}[1]{\def\@cauthor{#1}}


% Set PDF/A properties using pdfx and filecontens packages
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\AtEndPreamble{
  \RequirePackage[a-3b]{pdfx}
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.xmpdata}
  \Title{Certificate of Calibration No \@cnumber} % not working because \@cnumber not defined
  \Author{\@cauthor} % not working because \@cauthor not defined
\end{filecontents}

\endinput
```